# Vuejs: Axios post JSON data and Image data

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, post, axios

Currently, I am creating a form with image data and JSON data. I am using 2 post method to post image data and JSON data separately to my nodejs backend. Is it any possible solution that enables me to post once for image and JSON data only by using axios and backend by using nodejs.

The following is my code.

Frontend **vue.js**

```
submitAuth() {
  console.log(this.promo.bannerImg)
  const formData = new FormData()
  formData.append('bannerImg', this.promo.bannerImg)
  formData.append('inAppImg', this.promo.inAppImg)
  formData.append('inAppImg', this.promo)

   axios.post(`http://localhost:5000/success`, 
       this.promo
     )
     .then(response => { 
       console.log('Submit Success')
     })
     .catch(e => {
       console.log('Submit Fail')
     })

  axios.post('http://localhost:5000/uploadImg', 
      formData
  ).then(response => {
    console.log('Submit Success')
  }).catch(e => {
    console.log('Submit Fail')
  })
},
```

},

Backend **node.js**

```
app.post("/success", function (request, response) {
  co(function* () {
    var promouid = request.body.uid
    var filename = __dirname + '/public/promo-json/' +  promouid + '.json'
    var promotionJSON = JSON.stringify(request.body)
    fs.writeFile(filename, promotionJSON, 'utf-8', function (err) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log(request.body);
    });

    var stream = fs.createReadStream(filename);
    var size = fs.statSync(filename).size;
    var result = yield client.putStream( 
     'promojson/' + promouid + '.json', stream, {contentLength: size});
    console.log(result);
  }).catch(function (err) {
    console.log(err);
  });
});

app.post("/uploadImg", function (req, res) {
  var storage = multer.diskStorage({
        destination: 'public/image', 
        filename: function ( req, file, cb ) {
          // set image name
          console.log()
          cb( null,  'asdasdsad-' + Date.now());
      }
    });
    var upload = multer({
        storage: storage,
    }).any();

    upload(req, res, function(err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return res.end('Error');
        } else {
            console.log(req.body);
            req.files.forEach(function(item) {
                console.log(item);
            });
          res.end('File uploaded');
        }
    });
  });
```

Comment: how bout you convert the image to a base64encoded string on the client  and push that to the server in the same post request. You just need to convert back to file on the server. Ps: base64 most likely doubles the size of the file, compression on your server can come in handy

Comment: i dun think convert to base64 image is a good practice to pass image data to backend.

Comment: It has its use case and for what I know, it's not terrible to practise if you are already working with strings. You don't even need to decode before saving. you can just save the string wherever.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You would probably be better off using [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) for everything you need to upload if you want to use a single request to upload everything.

You could take your JSON data, serialize it to a string and then add it to the FormData along with the image.

Your frontend **vue.js** would look something like this:

```
const formData = new FormData();

// Add images to form data
formData.append('bannerImg', this.promo.bannerImg)
formData.append('inAppImg', this.promo.inAppImg)
formData.append('inAppImg', this.promo)

// Add the serialized JSON data to the formData (not
// sure what your JSON object is called)
formData.append('data', JSON.stringify(this.data));

// Submit the form data 
axios.post('http://localhost:5000/uploadImg', 
  formData
).then(response => {
  console.log('Submit Success')
}).catch(e => {
  console.log('Submit Fail')
});
```

In the back-end you would simply deserialize the *data* field in the FormData that is sent to a JSON object and you can then use it.

Comment: But hows is the image uploaded using this?

Comment: You can use the same code you were using to save files submitted to the /upload endpoint (`req.files.forEach(...)`) in the /success endpoint.  You would just retrieve the JSON from one of the FormData fields and then loop through the uploaded files and save them.